# How to save the .txt file on the pc directories where the system is accessed (Python)

Tags: python, file, path, directory

I wanted to export a txt file but the directory that it can only locate is where my server is installed.

Scenario:
My Server is in Ubuntu and I'm accessing my web-based system in Windows browsers, Whenever I generate a txt file it is saved in the /opt instead in the /downloads of the PC that I used. Is it possible to locate the ANY PC's active directory?
or any possible solution?

I tried os.chdir(C:\Windows\System32)
but it can't locate that path

Thanks in advance.
[EDIT]

```
a = random.randint(1, 9999)
name = 'debTest' + str(a * 7) + '.txt'
completeName = os.path.join('./Downloads', name)
print 'completname', completeName
file = open(completeName, 'w')
file.write("TEST FILE")
file = open(completeName, 'r')
file.close()
```

I'm trying this code:

Comment: Are you writing a program?  If so, please post the code that is not working for you.  BTW the current working directory can be obtained in a Python script as `os.getcwd()`.  It's the same for any platform.

Comment: @PaulCornelius here is the code I tried just now, but still didn't work:
(I'll edit the post above)

Comment: Close the file immediate after you're done writing to it - typically a file will be empty until it is closed.  Then when you open the file to read it, the text you wrote will be in there.  You should also see the file in Windows Explorer and it should not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your Ubuntu system through the web I'm guessing that you are running a web server there. You have to find out the dir on the Ubuntu system which you can have access to the web server (document root probably) and save the files there so you can bring them to your Windows PC using your browser building an URL like: 'http://ubuntuserver.example/MYFILE_SAVED_THERE.TXT'.